# PHP-File Downloading

Tags: php

I have uploaded multiple files for a training and I list them according to the training_ID. How can i download a single file associated with the training_id which have multiple files? 
I have .txt,.pdf,.docx and .pptx file types.
Here is the PHP file that i have tried.

```
<?php
$id= $_GET['id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","pass","test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$query = "SELECT Material_Name,Material_Data from Training_Material where     Training_Id='{$id}'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($result) 
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['Material_Name']);    
    echo $row['Material_Data'];
    @mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else 
{
    echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$mysqli->error}</pre>";
}
?>
```

With this file download is not happening.

Here Material_Data column in the DB contains the contents of the uploaded file whis is got using file_get_contents method. What should i do to make the download happen?

Comment: Off topic, but if you're using `mysqli` (which is a very good thing), you should use prepared statement and variable binding instead of stuffing information into your SQL query. For the download thing, try to add `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my sites where I have multiple license data available what I do is copy all the required license files to a temp folder, create a zip archive containing tham all and then push the zip file to the end user and delete the temp file data.

This has a couple of benefits single file download, compressed file so less to download easing bandwidth stress.  Also has a couple of disadvantages of processor usage for compiling zip and disk IO for moving files around. However I decided that on modern hardware IO/CPU are almost irrelevent on all but the largest of sites.

Answer (score 0):

You should send an content-type header like this:

```
header("Content-Type: plain/text");
```